# PHP Setting select as variable

Tags: php, mysql, select, if-statement

How can i make piece of select statement as php variable?
Example:
I have 2 options in select statement - edit and delete... I have those 2 options in dropdown menu... I want to make an mySQL query to edit or delete records/users from database...I tried to use switch and cases but it only gave me default as selecting.

```
<select name="editSelector">
<option name='edit'>Edit</option>
<option name='delete'>Delete</option>
</select>
<?php  
if (select == edit)
{
edit query here
}
elseif (select == delete)
{
delete query here
}
?>
```

I know that this code doesn't have any variables etc. Because i have no idea how to make option as variable. It's connected to database already. Thanks for the answer in advance.

Comment: try to use ajax because you cannot access php script once page is loaded

Comment: I'm an begginer in php/mysql and it's school project - i have no experience in ajax

Comment: Babar is right use Ajax and onchange as your function and post method.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <?php
    if($_REQUEST['editSelector'] == "edit"){
edit here;
}
else if ($_REQUEST['editSelector'] == "delete"){
delete here;
}
    ?>
```

Plus :

```
    <select name="editSelector">
<option value='edit'>Edit</option>
<option value='delete'>Delete</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I tried it already didn't worked ;) Always error that editSelector is a string not variable

Comment: your option should have "value" not "name".

Answer (score 0):

you need to place your `select > option` list in a form and process it the proper way using `POST`.

I would strongly advise **against** using ajax to facilitate any crud activity in your database.  Unless you know what youre doing its VERY insecure.

[heres](http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-processing.html) a reasonable web resource if you need to look things up.

**HTML file**

```
<form name='option_form' action='someProcessingFile.php' method='post'>
    <select name="editSelector">
       <option value='edit'>Edit</option>
       <option value='delete'>Delete</option>
    </select>

    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'/>
</form>
```

**someProcessingFile.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['editSelector']) {
    switch($_POST['editSelector']) {
        case 'edit':
            // do something here, probably with the rest of the form
            break;
        case 'delete':
            $id = htmlspecialchars($_POST['id']);
            // do something here and delete the entry
            break;
        default:
            // do something here to let yourself know that it all went wrong for some reason.
    }
}
```